# Make directories executable

Tags: permissions, directory

How may I add execute permission to all subdirectories of the current directory for the owner, the group owner, and all other users? Regular files should not be changed.

Comment: What research you did? Here we are not scripting service.

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` to identify subdirectories, and `chmod` to add permission:

```
$ find . -type d -exec chmod a+x {} \;
```

Comment: Without `! -path .`, this would also change the permissions of the current directory, which, strictly speaking, the question did not say should happen (it only mentions subdirectories of the current directory). (And to be even more strict, the question did not mention to do this recursively either.)